# How to get user screen_name in Tweepy with V2 API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm specifically using V2 API with tweepy and am struggling to get what was user screen_name. The best I have is:

`tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query,expansions='author_id',max_results=10)`

This would need a round trip to get user_name. Surely there has to be a way to do it in a single query?

Also, screen_name is username in V2, but that still has me no closer as that's not an accepted parameter for either fields or expansions.

Reference https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/migrate/standard-to-twitter-api-v2

Well after more searching ... it was not obvious:

`tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query,tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], expansions='entities.mentions.username',max_results=10)`

Reference https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent#Optional

But the user.fields parameter mentioned in the above still doesn't work.

Comment: So retweets have the the entities object, new original tweets don't ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet the username is listed as an available field in the `user.fields` enum.

You can add it to your last request:

```
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query,tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], expansions='entities.mentions.username', max_results=10, user_fields=['username']
```

But you should use the `author_id` expansion if you want the username of the tweet's author.

Please also note that the username will be in the `includes` dict (at the root), not in the `data` one.

Comment: Ok, thank you, nothing is that easy with the V2 API so get the author_id and then lookup in the users dict returned ... so ended up with
`tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query,tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], expansions=['entities.mentions.username','author_id'], max_results=max_results, user_fields=['username'])`